# Strange TypeScript typing issue (TS error code 2349)

Tags: typescript, types

Why do I get a compile error with the following code snippet?

```
let f: (() => void) | null = null

function g() {
  f = () => {}
}

g()

if (f) {
  f() // <- Error: "This expression is not callable 
      //            Type 'never' has no call signatures. (2349)"
}
```

[TypeScript Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/DYUwLgBAZgXBAU8CUEC8A+CA3A9gSwBMUAfCAOwFdhg1yrgAoBqCsgYzDxzIgHNkIAbwYRotARiEBfBjIb8kTPFARQUw0VAEB6bRAA8AWggBRAE5mcZuACIAKgAs8AZwggAHgAczIZ8648LuQ4kGwAhtRhAEagECKiCboJySl2AJ6eIBAA5GQgWCBm2RAOYa5kOBDh1BD+vGRhYBQ+zgB0CABMAMwALACcSDayQA)

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because TypeScript doesn't know that `g` assigns to `f`, its flow analysis for the purposes of narrowing types doesn't go that deep. As a result, when it reaches `if (f)` it thinks `f` is `null` (because it's narrowed the type based on the assignment that it **did** see, so it thinks that `f` has the type `null` at that point), so within the `if` the type of `f` has been narrowed further to `never` (because TypeScript thinks you'll never go into that `if`), which isn't callable. You can see this if you hover your mouse over `f` in the `if` condition (it says the type is `null`) and then hover over it in the body of the `if` (it says the type is `never`).

If you tweak your example so that TypeScript's flow analysis can see that `f` may not be `null` anymore, the error goes away:

```typescript
let f: (() => void) | null = null

if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  f = () => {}
}

if (f) {
  f() // <- Error: "This expression is not callable 
      //            Type 'never' has no call signatures. (2349)"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/DYUwLgBAZgXBAU8CUEC8A+CA3A9gSwBMUAfCAOwFdhg1yrgAoBvKBAWQEMwALAOgCcOZAjgC2yCAB4IABl4BWFAG8GEaLQkYISgL4M9zVvCjLV0CQHoLUgLQQAov345+cAEQAVbngDOEEAAeAA78ID4+eDhkEL7kOJAAxhzUHABGoBBmampW2Xn5HgCeQSAQAORkIFgg-GUQ3Bx+ZDgQSdQQEQDmZFwUoT68CABMAMwALACcSG76QA)

I suspect (but don't know) that this is just one of several pragmatic limits on the analysis that the TypeScript compiler has to ensure that performance is acceptable. [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) provides [this illuminating link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) discussing the trade-offs and issues. The take-away message is: Control-flow analysis doesn't cross function boundaries.

Comment: This has got [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) written all over it.  "Control flow analysis doesn't cross function boundaries, sorry" is probably a good short title for it.

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks for the link! Amusing summary, too. :-) Do you know if there's a dupetarget we should be using for this? I feel like there has to be one...